# Splitting an Url with slashes and recombining them sequentially (angular, typescript)

Tags: angular, typescript, breadcrumbs

I'm trying to create Breadcrumbs navigation and I'm stuck while creating parent URLs.

So my idea is:

1. get a full URL from child level
2. splitting that URL with slashes and recombining them sequentially

So simply if the URL is:

```
www.nice.com/events/registration/form
```

then, split to like:

```
www.nice.com/events/registration/form
```

```
www.nice.com/events/registration
```

```
www.nice.com/events
```

```
www.nice.com
```

and reverse the order and push into array like:

```
['www.nice.com', 'www.nice.com/events', 'www.nice.com/events/registration', 'www.nice.com/events/registration/form']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the URL's [`pathname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/pathname) on the URL path separator character `/` and then iterate the path parts to build your list:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQBSwCwGcAKEFAGwC5EBVAJQBkBKagbXoYBpEA6Pj1gF1BiAN4AoRMgSEoiAA4FC1ASIC8iIQG5xkxDGCJSFHoqj4wGALZpEa+4gBEAekdMxeqWaKmQhfMRgaADutIzG5KYEljbcZJFwKDAA5jBgTEw6UgC+iGjkhLYSUlIQMnLeeChQhHaI8VHmMWg8hPLkMFDELm5ZJcCJRuRocjB1AAxa+ogAPAoEVTU8w2DJ5lNjANQaAIzuxSVeSr7+gSFhDMSVGNWErR0QaMTj3FuIezwAVnBp3a5McRMiRSaQyfRyemyuikzmciBwcEIhBgACNyABPRAAEzQyPQWOoAElDOZbGl5CA5BxEPgMLUAI4gNAoTGDYAoDDJGxgORYrAYTh6WGIDBYrEixDANIYcgXRBQODy-C2DqyRDBfAwCD4fSQcggHG1cxYbH8yh6AxGBqFG7axAAH3t9RMtP8+080jAaqllnINAodSCoQ4V2OWGIAFo9gBCTIen0y-2RG0oO0aa2YVP4cGS6V+l10nXpgv+HPeO4U04J-PkOMQvToKBkJDlkW1diMbh8HiqQQ6KHiMpeuTxQPnEOOfBQKDyZSw4ILnhgLUtMpWZxoABuaB5hGc6FSsg5sAQzgGKCsvUH5Xm5lqGlQmGweDvETjQ8IcGGyzgyVDd7ja8vS-FpyF-Yg9EfLBcCUCDDiDC5uinGc52cBdgiXFceDXDdt13fc0EPKBj3gMAz0SKwAH4AGs0HRNRNxlJkAGIBjgbAUDcQUpABcQ4yAA)

```ts
function createPaths(url: URL): [URL, ...URL[]] {
  const paths: URL[] = [];

  if (url.pathname === "/") {
    paths.push(new URL(url.pathname, url.origin));
  } else {
    const pathParts = url.pathname.split("/");
    for (let i = 0; i < pathParts.length; i += 1) {
      paths.push(new URL(pathParts.slice(0, i + 1).join("/"), url.origin));
    }
  }

  // Possibly desired: If the input URL has query or fragment data,
  // add a final URL to the list which includes that data:
  if (url.search || url.hash) {
    const finalUrl = new URL(paths.at(-1)!);
    finalUrl.search = url.search;
    finalUrl.hash = url.hash;
    paths.push(finalUrl);
  }

  return paths as [URL, ...URL[]];
}

const url = new URL("https://www.nice.com/events/registration/form");
const paths = createPaths(url);
console.log(paths); // ["https://www.nice.com/","https://www.nice.com/events","https://www.nice.com/events/registration","https://www.nice.com/events/registration/form"]

console.log(createPaths(new URL("https://www.nice.com/events/registration/form?key=value#footer"))); // ["https://www.nice.com/","https://www.nice.com/events","https://www.nice.com/events/registration","https://www.nice.com/events/registration/form","https://www.nice.com/events/registration/form?key=value#footer"]
```

Compiled JS from the playground:

```js
"use strict";
function createPaths(url) {
    const paths = [];
    if (url.pathname === "/") {
        paths.push(new URL(url.pathname, url.origin));
    }
    else {
        const pathParts = url.pathname.split("/");
        for (let i = 0; i < pathParts.length; i += 1) {
            paths.push(new URL(pathParts.slice(0, i + 1).join("/"), url.origin));
        }
    }
    if (url.search || url.hash) {
        const finalUrl = new URL(paths.at(-1));
        finalUrl.search = url.search;
        finalUrl.hash = url.hash;
        paths.push(finalUrl);
    }
    return paths;
}
const url = new URL("https://www.nice.com/events/registration/form");
const paths = createPaths(url);
console.log(paths);
console.log(createPaths(new URL("https://www.nice.com/events/registration/form?key=value#footer")));
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working propery with my project!